# Why does an Android App launch in the background when running from Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

When pressing "Run" in Android Studio 4.0, sometimes my app will launch in the background on the device - a tablet running Android 7.0. Meaning I'll have to go to the "Recent Items" view on the device and press on the app there to open. The app doesn't launch on the foreground as normal.

When this happens, there are no logs shown in the "Run" View Window in Android Studio - even after opening the app from the "Recent Items" view.

I reached out to Google and have not had much success resolving. I was wondering if anyone here has come across this, or has an idea what this might be.

Reproducing on an Emulator, but not on a new empty project.

EDIT: Adding logs - these are grabbed from the device straight using an `adb shell logcat` command. These problems happen only when the app is already running, and began happening after upgrading to Android Studio 4.0. My app's name is `poscosecha` and the full package name is `com.plantecuador.poscosecha`. The device is an RCA 10" Tablet with Android 7.0 (API 24). The error reproduces on an emulator with the same version of Android. It does not occur 100% of the time, but definitely more than 75% if the app is already running.

There are two distinct error cases. In the first, the app moves to the background. In the second, the app shuts down completely (does not appear in background tasks). The first case seems to occur more often if there are changes between runs, while the second occurs more often if there are no changes.

Logcat for the first case:

https://pastebin.com/T1HFU9zb

Logcat for the second case:

https://pastebin.com/qJque7A7

EDIT 2: Adding Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.plantecuador.poscosecha">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <!-- Bluetooth printer permissions -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash" android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="false" /> <!-- Access fine & coarse location is used to determine the macaddress & bluetooth address -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        tools:replace="android:allowBackup">
        <activity android:name=".SignInActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"  />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: just in case, try going to AVD list, choose missbehaving emulator, wipe data.

Comment: Thanks but it's not just on an emulator - this also occurs on a real device.

Comment: does this happen everytime? Where do you check for logs? In the run window or the logcat window. Also is your logcat showing logs??

Comment: I've been expeeriencing the same issue for quite a few months now, Galaxy S10+ and AS 4.0 as well.

Comment: Something in the background couldn't be shutdown so the new code can't be deployed. What in the background is the old version. It may eventually die.

Comment: @TimTimWong could you elaborate more on "it may eventually die"?

Comment: "The app shut down completely" => "it dies". When you hit `Run` it first has to stop the app (if running) before deploying the new build and then starting it. If that shutting down times out, it won't start.

Comment: can you share your launcher activity Manifest. try adding android:alwaysRetainTaskState="true"  android:launchMode="singleTask"
to your launcher activity

Comment: @alokHarman added it to the question. Adding those two props to the launcher activity didn't solve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: I have the same problem sometimes

Comment: Not sure why it is doing it, but it should be simple to work around...

Answer (score 0):

`android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"` may be causing the issue. If the tablet is on landscape mode, it may deny to go portrait mode without user interaction.

Comment: The tablet is in Portrait throughout the process